# Use query column within subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

```
INVOICES
ID | DISCOUNT_PRC
1  |   NULL
2  |   0.10
3  |   0.70
...

INVOICE_ITEMS
ID | INVOICE_ID | PRICE | ALT_PRICE
1  |     1      |  100  |  0
2  |     1      |  200  |  150
3  |     2      |  400  |  300
4  |     2      |  200  |  0
5  |     2      |  100  |  NULL
6  |     3      |  200  |  40
7  |     3      |  100  |  NULL
...
```

NOTE: The database is being used by another application, I am not allowed to change zeros to `NULL` values or vice versa.

I need to output the sum of items for each invoice, with `PRICE` of each item being multiplied by the discount `(1 - DISCOUNT_PRC)`, except if the `ALT_PRICE` is not `NULL` and is greater than zero. In that case, just take the `ALT_PRICE`. So, the desired output would be like this:

```
INVOICES
ID | OVERALL_PRICE
1  |    250     (100*1) + (150)
2  |    570       (300) + (200*0.9) + (100*0.9)
3  |     70        (40) + (100*0.3)
```

What I have so far:

```
select I.ID,
     case when ISNULL( IT.ALT_PRICE, 0) > 0
          then IT.ALT_PRICE
          else IT.PRICE * (1 - ISNULL( I.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
          end AS OVERALL_PRICE
from INVOICES I
join INVOICE_ITEMS IT on IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
```

The result

```
ID  OVERALL_PRICE
1   100
1   150
2   300
2   180
2   90
3   40
3   30
```

The result is valid for each item, now I need to `SUM` them in one row for each invoice. I tried that using `LEFT JOIN` and then with `OUTER_APPLY`:

```
select I.ID, items.OVERALL_PRICE FROM INVOICES I
OUTER APPLY ( select sum (
     case when ISNULL( IT.ALT_PRICE, 0) > 0
          then IT.ALT_PRICE
          else IT.PRICE * (1 - ISNULL( I.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
          end) AS OVERALL_PRICE
from INVOICE_ITEMS IT
where IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
group by IT.INVOICE_ID ) as items
```

But I get the same error:

`Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.`

**EDIT:**
I would also like to avoid having `SUM` (or any other aggregated expression) within my main query columns, as that would require all other columns to be grouped. The actual table has 50+ columns and some other subqueries so I want to avoid that.

**EDIT 2:**
Okay, I've made some benchmarking with solutions from B3S (join within subquery), iSR5(OVER) and Gordon Linoff (APPLY). I have inserted 50k invoices and 500k invoice items and I used MSSQL `STATISTICS`, it should show decent enough results, based on the database size. Here are the results:

```
Join within subquery:
- CPU time = 1170 ms,  elapsed time = 335 ms.
- CPU time = 1202 ms,  elapsed time = 344 ms.
- CPU time = 1153 ms,  elapsed time = 348 ms.

OVER:
- CPU time = 3089 ms,  elapsed time = 1361 ms.
- CPU time = 3010 ms,  elapsed time = 1075 ms.
- CPU time = 3010 ms,  elapsed time = 1070 ms.

APPLY:
- CPU time = 2496 ms,  elapsed time = 2320 ms.
- CPU time = 2433 ms,  elapsed time = 2171 ms.
- CPU time = 2496 ms,  elapsed time = 2179 ms.
```

**Conclusion:**
I did expect for the join within subquery to be optimized by the SQL, but I was still expecting to see better results with the other two suggestions. This is quite a surprise for me, but I have to give credit (and accepted answer) to B3S. I was sure the inner join would cause a blow to the performance, I didn't bother to try it. Anyway, do not hesitate to join the outer table from within subquery - if needed, ofcourse.

Comment: Is `1  |    250     (100*0) + (150)` a mistake and should rather read `1  |    150     (100*0) + (150)`?

Comment: It was a mistake, yes, but it should read `1 | 250  (100*1) + (150)`, since the discount is `NULL` i.e. 0 and I am multiplying by `(1-discount)`. Good catch, it is corrected now.

Comment: Your SQL references a column DISCOUNT but your schema defines a column DISCOUNT_PRC.

Comment: @webmite Yup, I wrote as `DISCOUNT_PRC` here to make it more clear it is percentage, but forgot to change it in other places. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
select I.ID,
     sum(case when ISNULL( IT.ALT_PRICE, 0) > 0
          then IT.ALT_PRICE
          else IT.PRICE * (1 - ISNULL( I.DISCOUNT, 0))
          end) AS OVERALL_PRICE
from INVOICES I
join INVOICE_ITEMS IT on IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
GROUP BY I.ID
```

Edit based on your comment:

```
select DISTINCT
     I.TESTFIELD1,
     I.TESTFIELD2,
     I.ID,
     (SELECT SUM(case when ISNULL( IT2.ALT_PRICE, 0) > 0
          then IT2.ALT_PRICE
          else IT2.PRICE * (1 - ISNULL( I2.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
          end)
     FROM INVOICES I2
     LEFT JOIN INVOICE_ITEMS IT2 ON IT2.INVOICE_ID = I2.ID
     WHERE I2.ID = I.ID
     GROUP BY I2.ID) AS OVERALL_PRICE
from INVOICES I
join INVOICE_ITEMS IT on IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
```

I've added some testfields in order to show you how you can use `sum` and avoid `group by` each table field.

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a6ab5/6)

Comment: I forgot to write in my question that I would like to avoid the endless stream of `GROUP BY`'s, the actual table is a lot larger, it would also mess my other subqueries. Any idea to make it without it?

Comment: Well, it is working. But you are selecting the outer (`INVOICES`) table again within the subquery. It crossed my mind, but I figured it would make a blow to the performance. Am I wrong? I guess I have some benchmarking to do...

Comment: yep i am, in order to avoid the group by problem. The sql fiddle can help you to make things more clear. About performances: if INVOICES.ID is indexed, you shouldn't experience hard performance issues, at least not more than expected from an aggregate function.

Comment: You were right, check the numbers I added in the question post.

Answer (score 1):

Your `apply` method should work without the `group by`, in my opinion.

```
select I.ID, items.OVERALL_PRICE
FROM INVOICES I OUTER APPLY
     (select sum(case when IT.ALT_PRICE > 0
                      then IT.ALT_PRICE
                      else IT.PRICE * (1 - coalesce( I.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
                 end) AS OVERALL_PRICE
      from INVOICE_ITEMS IT
      where IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
     ) items;
```

Note that the initial condition requires no `NULL` check`, because`NULL`will fails almost all comparisons.  If`ALT_PRICE`is never negative or zero, you can simply use`COALESCE()`:

```
select I.ID, items.OVERALL_PRICE
FROM INVOICES I OUTER APPLY
     (select sum(coalesce(IT.ALT_PRICE,
                          IT.PRICE * (1 - coalesce( I.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
                         )
                ) AS OVERALL_PRICE
      from INVOICE_ITEMS IT
      where IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
     ) as items;
```

But it doesn't in SQL Server.  I'm not sure why SQL Server has this limitation on outer references.  It seems strange.

In this case, you can rewrite the logic as:

```
select I.ID, items.OVERALL_PRICE
from INVOICES I outer apply
     (select (sum(case when IT.ALT_PRICE > 0 then IT.ALT_PRICE else 0 END) +
              sum(case when IT.ALT_PRICE = 0 OR IT.ALT_PRICE IS NULL
                       then IT.PRICE else 0
                  end) * (1 - coalesce( I.DISCOUNT_PRC, 0))
             ) AS OVERALL_PRICE
      from INVOICE_ITEMS IT
      where IT.INVOICE_ID = I.ID
     ) items;
```

This is not as satisfying but you can use `apply`.

Comment: Thank you, but there were faster solutions, upvote will have to do for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to take advantage of `OVER()` which will avoids you from using `GROUP BY`

You could do something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Inv.ID,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN items.ALT_Price IS NOT NULL AND items.ALT_Price > 0 
            THEN items.ALT_Price
            ELSE items.Price * (1 - ISNULL(DISCOUNT_PRC, 0 ))
    END) OVER(PARTITION BY Inv.ID ORDER BY Inv.ID) AS OVERALL_PRICE
FROM #Invoices Inv
JOIN #Invoices_Items items ON items.Inovice_ID = Inv.ID
```

you can then add columns without enclosing them inside `GROUP BY`

you can also use it as sub-query :

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
    Inv.ID,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN items.ALT_Price IS NOT NULL AND items.ALT_Price > 0 
            THEN items.ALT_Price
            ELSE items.Price * (1 - ISNULL(DISCOUNT_PRC, 0 ))
    END) OVER(PARTITION BY Inv.ID ORDER BY Inv.ID) AS OVERALL_PRICE
FROM #Invoices Inv
JOIN #Invoices_Items items ON items.Inovice_ID = Inv.ID
) D 
-- extend it with more filters, JOINs ..etc
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the benchmarking showed it is not the best one. (check question post edit). Fastest solution will get accepted, just an upvote for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I would choose (pending performance analysis versus other methods):

```
select i.ID
     , sum(coalesce(alt_price,price*(1-isnull(discount_prc,0)))) OVERALL_PRICE
  from invoices i
  join (select id
             , invoice_id
             , price
             , case alt_price when 0 then null else alt_price end alt_price
          from invoice_items) ii
    on i.id = ii.invoice_id
 group by i.id
```

In this query `alt_price`s of zero are first converted to `NULL` then `coalesce` is used inside a `sum` to pick either the `alt_price` or the discounted `price`.